# In a systemd service, how can I kill all processes on restart, other than $MAINPID?

Tags: service, systemd

I wrote a simple `.service` for systemd.
**My process** starts fine, but it **spans more sub-processes with different PIDs**.

Hence, I can not properly stop my service with the usual line:

```
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
```

because I kill the main original process (a shell script), but not its children.

How can I *kill 'em all* on restart? Is there a valid macro like $ALLPIDS?

(I am working with Ubuntu 16.04.)

Thanks,
F